# Web3 (python) - confirming transaction hash format

Tags: web3js, python, database

Due to the fact, that I am storing txId obtained from the user, before determining whether transaction has been ended or not, I want to make sure that the transaction hash, which will be stored in my database, has a correct format.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction hash is the result of hashing the rlp-encoded transaction with `keccak256()` (many APIs erroneously call it `sha3()`). The hash produces 32 bytes data. When hex-encoded, that produces 64 hex characters (0-9, a-f, or A-F), plus usually an "0x" prefix. For example:

```
"0x0123456789abcdefABCDEF0123456789abcdefABCDEF0123456789abcdefABCD"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just used following regex:
r"^(0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{64})$"